# I have two table on one view one is custom table and other is simple table how to show data on both table?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios-simulator

I have two table views.

One is simple and the other is custom. I am getting values though JSON. I'm making one JSON request at a time but when I call both JSON requests for the simple table and the custom table it displays the data on the custom table but suddenly after that the simple table loads but it hides the data of the first custom table.

Does anyone know why this happens?

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    if (tableView==self.table) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(tableView==self.clearificationTable){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (tableView==self.table) {
        return [reminderArrayList count];
    }
    else if(tableView==self.clearificationTable) {
        return [taskListArray count];
    }
    return 0;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{
    if (tableView==self.table) {
        UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text=[reminderArrayList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        newCell=cell;
     }
     else if (tableView==self.clearificationTable) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
        StaffDahsBoardCustom *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"StaffDahsBoardCustom" owner:self options:nil];
        }
        cell=custom;
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        cell.taskListlbl.text=[taskListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.tasktypelbl.text=[tasktypeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.completelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[completeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.incompletelbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[incompleteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.nalbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NaArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.returnlbl.text=[ReturneDateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        newCell=cell;        
    }
    return newCell;
}
```

Comment: Give each a different tag. `[tableView setTag:]`

Comment: Why -1 My answer is right ?

Comment: Make habit of proper formatting of code... I am tired now....ufff

Comment: gopal ji..answer to accept karo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tag value for table.

```
firstTable.tag=1;

secondTable.tag=2;
```